# What kind of proxy is that?

Tags: proxy, tcp

Please consider the following scenario:

**Host1** has a public IP
***Host2*** doesn't

Hosts are in different networks.

***Host2*** is running a web service (yes, ***Host2***)
**Host1** is a client for it

I understand that to provide accessibility to ***Host2*** from **Host1**:
1) I can set up a VPN, but this is too much just for one communicating channel.
2) I can use SSH connection with remote forwarding (-R option), but again - this is too much
3) I can set up Jabber server on **Host1** and Jabber client on ***Host2*** and communicate through the XMPP messaging protocol - nice option but looking for more unattended solution

I'm interested in finding a software that allows to set up a persistent socket connection between these hosts and map web service port from ***Host2*** to **Host1**.

Please advise to what type of proxy this scenario conforms and is there any software for that?

UPDATE: A good rephrase for this question: How to map a listening port from ***Host2*** to **Host1**?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)

You run up an HTTP listener (e.g. Apache using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)) on host1 and configure it to proxy requests to host2.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I left one of the main points unclear - both hosts are in different networks... Would it change your answer or I'm missing something?

Comment: You need some way of allowing host1 to send/receive data to host2, either by allowing traffic to be directly routed from one network to the other or by setting up a VPN connection.  If host1 can't talk to host2 at all then you've got an air-gap between the networks and you're stuffed I'm afraid.

Comment: Sadly but that is the question - how to handle this air-gap, without VPN or SSH

Comment: Last attempt then - how about port forwarding using iptables (assumes host1 is a linux box) - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/iptables-port-forwarding-599401/